# ki wo tsukete kudasai / karada ni ki wo tsukete kudasai

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> 気をつけてください
> ki wo tsukete kudasai

> 体に気をつけてください
> karada ni ki wo tsukete kudasai

I learned that "ki wo tsukete kudasai" means "take care", "be careful"? In a different text the "karada ni" part was added.

Answer (score 5):

気をつけてください (ki wo tsukete kudasai) on its own just means " please take care". If you want to specify what you should take care of then that thing is marked with に (ni).

So 体に気をつけてください (karada ni ki wo tsukete kudasai) is literally "take care of your body", or more naturally just "look after yourself".

But the phrase can be used more generally e.g. 階段に気をつけてください (kaidan ni ki wo tsukete kudasai) -> "Please watch out for the stairs".

Also note that I corrected 'karadi' to 'karada'. There is no 'di' sound in Japanese. It was probably just a typo, but just making sure.

Comment: "No 'di' sound in Japanese" may be misleading, as it frequently appears in loanwords.

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth Fair point. It's certainly safe to say there's no 'di' in hiragana. I'd like to also claim that no kanji will ever have a 'di' sound in it, but then I'm not certain that kanji haven't been invented for some loan words. What would you say the most general claim we could make was?

Comment: Maybe something like "no 'di' in traditional words" because it occurs not only in loanwords but also in new coinages like Pokémon names. Hiragana and kanji are irrelevant because it's about how to write it. Kan'on and go'on don't have 'di' but Mandarin transcriptions actually do.